# login issue with database in php

Tags: php

I have made a login form using php , but when the username and password field is empty it still login

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con,"admincontrol");

$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from admin where username = '$username' and password = '$password'") or die("Faile to query database".mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password){
    header( 'Location: http://localhost/DoctorPro/fetch2.php' ) ; 
} 
else{
    header( 'Location: http://localhost/DoctorPro/fail.html' ) ;     
}    
?>
```

Comment: Please read it [ask]

Comment: what you mean about user still login, if both fields are empty???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check if the row is empty:

```
if($row && $row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password){
```